# website is not opening in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to open a url in my webview but the problem is that the url is not loading in my webview, its showing pop-up for the selection of browser and as soon as i click on an option it opens the url in that browser. Can somebody help me to solve this, i want the url to open in the webview itself not in the browser.

my xml for webview is :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_new" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wbview_bckbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn_chng" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upBar" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/linkwebview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my code for webview :-

```
public class FbTwtrLink extends Activity {

    WebView web;
    ImageView img,bckimg,share_btn; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_twtr_link);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header);
        bckimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wbview_bckbtn);

        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.linkwebview);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_fb_twtr_link, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and i m calling the webview like that :-

```
fbicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent intent=new Intent(context,FbTwtrLink.class);
                //intent.putExtra("fb_link", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `WebViewClient` and its method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
 web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient()); 
 web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //1 option 
    // getApplicationContext().startActivity(
    // new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    // 2 option
    //view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `getApplicationContext().startActivity(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))`

Comment: You are starting new Intent to view url but returning true so it opens in webview not default browser since you override it,this piece of code works for me fine

Comment: Wait what? That startActivity should not be there. It should be view.loadUrl(url); return true; Else the browser selection windows shows up

Comment: Well as I said It works for me, there is no harm to try to put view.loadUrl(url); and try that also

Comment: and @vodich thnks for this method its working after doing some changes

Comment: LOL a solutionposted 8 years ago still is valid today.  Just used this, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line may help:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

also add internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also if using API lever greater equal to 11 then you can use this in you manifest at application level

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: DONE THAT BUT IT IS AGAIN ASKING FOR BROWSER OPTION AND IT IS NOT OPENING IT IN WEBVIEW

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below statement to open in webview:

```
mweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Direct this >

```
   fbicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent (android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("http://www,google.com")); // Prepare intent
        startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
```